# Get sample request/response by using/analyzing given URL alone

Tags: java, web-services, middleware

I am going to develop one middleware for backend communication. The request from client system is converted to server specific request by the middleware. This middleware would be able to support any kind of server.

For client request, i am going to use XML/JSON format. The middleware has to convert XML/JSON format to server specific format by analyzing the URL given by client in runtime(it may be SOAP, WSDL, HTTP etc).

My question is, Is there any way to analyze the URL in runtime? Means, I have to find request type(whether SOAP/HTTP,GET/POST).

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Have you consider using ESB product or you have to develop standalone/web java application ? Your requirements sounds to me as perfect example for EAI solution.

Comment: I am going to develop it own. I don't know about ESB/EAI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use plain java, for data conversion you can use XPath/XSLT with great success (in fact most of ESB solutions are using it). By changing your XSLT templates you can apply changes at runtime without restarting your application.

Anyway you should consider solutions like [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org), [Mule](http://www.mulesoft.org/) and [Spring Integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration) which are specifically targeted in such problem domain. They will help you to separate business and transformation logic from transport.

As my additional advice use JMS when possible, it's much more reliable transport than HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to analyze URL at run=time!
For more details you will need to specify the platform you're going to use.

Want to draw your attention to few points, hope it helps: 
1) SOAP can be ran on top HTTP,TCP, email and many other transports... 
2) WSDL is not a protocol per say but rather a way to describe the data that one would send over SOAP.
3) GET/POST: usually every HTTP server no matter the language and/or platform will give you an information about the incoming request therefore you can differentiate that fairly easily

Comment: Thanks deian, for your reply.. I use java for this application. My question is, I want to convert XML/JSON request to server specific request at run time. Is this possible?